# Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" missing

Tags: postgresql

I try to run an application where its database on postgresql. It won't work and I'm getting the following error whenever I try to interact with the Postgres service:

```
could not connect to server: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`
```

I checked if Postgresql service is running

```
sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

```
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2019-04-04 10:28:27 +01; 58min ago
 Main PID: 1212 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 3522)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

avril 04 10:28:27 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
avril 04 10:28:27 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

checked the content of the socket unix connection

```
ls /var/run/postgresql/
```

got this empty folder

```
brahim@ubuntu:/var/log/postgresql$ ls /var/run/postgresql/
10-main.pg_stat_tmp
```

checked the content of the data directory

```
ls /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/
```

it contains the following

```
 base         pg_logical    pg_serial     pg_subtrans  pg_wal
 global       pg_multixact  pg_snapshots  pg_tblspc    pg_xact
 pg_commit_ts  pg_notify     pg_stat      pg_twophase  
 postgresql.auto.conf pg_dynshmem   pg_replslot   pg_stat_tmp   
 PG_VERSION   postmaster.opts
```

the file postgresql.conf has the following configuration

```
  # - Connection Settings -
  #listen_addresses = 'localhost'
  port = 5432
  max_connections = 100
  unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'
```

I tried to uncomment the listen_addresses instruction and it didn't work, also I've tried with '*' for all, same thing

the postgresql file log has

```
2019-04-04 12:17:57.765 +01 [942] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2019-04-04 12:17:57.767 +01 [942] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-04-04 12:17:58.190 +01 [971] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-04-03 20:19:54 +01
2019-04-04 12:17:58.192 +01 [971] PANIC:  replication checkpoint has wrong magic 1886413116 instead of 307747550
2019-04-04 12:17:59.900 +01 [942] LOG:  startup process (PID 971) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2019-04-04 12:17:59.900 +01 [942] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2019-04-04 12:17:59.902 +01 [942] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I am running postgresql 10.6
any thoughts

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, i've tried that, and i get the fallowing                                                                        
        #psql: could not connect to server: Connexion 
 refusée
 #Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 #TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Looking closer at the postgres log, it seems your data directory is corrupt: "*replication checkpoint has wrong magic 1886413116 instead of 307747550*" and the subsequent "*aborting startup due to startup process failure*". I don't know if that can be properly fixed, but one way would be to get rid of the current data directory, create a new one using `initdb` then restore your backup.

Comment: @dezso              
   >brahim@ubuntu:/etc/postgresql/10/main$ ls -la /var/run/postgresql
total 0
drwxrwsr-x  3 postgres postgres  60 avril  4 13:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 37 root     root     980 avril  4 12:18 ..
drwxr-s---  2 postgres postgres  40 avril  4 12:17 10-main.pg_stat_tmp
as i mentioned whatever commands you put in to interact with postgresql service it generates the same error code for example 'psql'

Comment: "replication checkpoint has wrong magic"  Is this server supposed to be using logical replication?  Is it the publisher or the subscriber?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name after that i creat a new one with `./initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data` the creation was done successfully, but i try to start it with the fallowing `sudo ./pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data -l logfile start` but i get permission denied error #pg_ctl: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will own the server process# i changed the owner of the /usr/local/pgsql/data/ to the usr brahim `ls - la /usr/local/pgsql/data/` got this #total 8 drwxr-xr-x 2 brahim brahim 4096 avril 4 13:55 . drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 avril 4 13:55

Comment: @jjanes i guess that is a comman error indicates that the server dosen't shut down cleanly

Comment: `initdb` and `pg_ctl` should be run as the Linux user `postgres`. **Not** as root.

Comment: See [here](http://www.jebriggs.com/blog/2018/05/postgresql-and-panic-replication-checkpoint-has-wrong-magic-error/) or [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/1511966240.1459861.1188109744.2D26AD08%40webmail.messagingengine.com)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name finaly i'v succeded to creat a new database, but i still don't know how to restor the old database to my new one, i'm not that familiar with postgresql can you write down the synopsis of restauring, would you please !

Comment: How did you fix this problem? I am having same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the `-a` option to `ls` to also show files starting with the period `.` character (i.e. "hidden" files):

```
$ ls -a /var/run/postgresql/
.  ..  .s.PGSQL.5432  .s.PGSQL.5432.lock
```

Answer (score -1):

Solución que me funcionó en Postgresql 11:

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster 11 main start
```

También revisar que tenga bien configurado  pg_hba.conf

Comment: Hi Idexan, any chance you can add some more detail about why you think his is wrong, and how to configure pg_hba.conf to make this go away? I see that you are using pg_ctlcluster but he isn't. (I could be wrong, I don't see it). This site is about Q&A, and having those answers is sure sometimes helpful, instead of just "copy-paste this it'll work".